# Bashrc file opens up continuously

Tags: raspbian, bash, terminal

When i turn on my raspberry pi in command line mode it opens up with bashrc each time i startup my pi.If i open my terminal the same bashrc script opens first.Can anyone give me a solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you've been misled by tutorials or blogs which imply or explicitly state that `.bashrc` can be used for things you want to happen at boot.<sup>1</sup> This is essentially **false**, although it has side effects that might make it seem that otherwise.

`.bashrc` is a shell initialization file.  There are a few different flavours of these, which you can read about in `man bash` under INVOCATION.   For example:

> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

You can think of an interactive shell as the command line. "An interactive shell that is not a login shell" applies to almost any shell that opens in a terminal, amongst other things. The "that is not a login shell" is often negated by the fact that `~/.profile` and/or `~/.bash_profile`, which are initialization files called when starting an interactive shell that *is*  a login shell, source `~/.bashrc`.  When this is the case, `.bashrc` is run when starting any interactive shell.

Booting the system and starting an interactive shell are very different events, so if you put something in `.bashrc` and expect it to run at boot, or to only run at boot, expect to be surprised.

---

1. Authors of which should be banned from posting anything about how to use computers on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Undo the modification you have done.

`Bashrc` is a simple file name and has no special meaning but the **bash** shell (that what makes the command line) uses a configuration file `$HOME/.bashrc`. Notice the dot at the beginning of the filename. It makes the configuration file invisible. You can show it with `ls -a`. Check if you have the `.bashrc` file.

Comment: I have been using UNIX/linux (as a casual user) for ages, but I still don't understand why and how to use the weird dot thing.  I still remember once upon a Rpi2 time it took me 3 hours to search for a invisible dotted file (and no luck and gave up!) .  To me Windows and Linux are relatively like heaven and hell.  Actually I gave up Rpi after Rpi1 altogether, only came back at Rpi3 when GUI has become barely bearable.  I hope Rpi5, Win10, with SuperShell, only for super users and never newbies.  I always think UNIX/C are for geeks with IQ above 120 (poor me only 97!)